# MQTT reconnect continuously

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I build a simple mqtt model for testing reconnection. I expect that it would reconnect once after it disconnect if reconnect successfully.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,reasonCode,properties):
    client.subscribe(topic)
    print('subscribed')

def on_disconnect(client,userdata,rc):
    print('disconnect')

client=mqtt.Client(protocol=5)
client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
client.connect('192.168.233.133')
client.loop_forever()
```

But it yields the following result.

```
subscribed
disconnect
subscribed
disconnect
subscribed
..........
```

What makes this problem?

Comment: What is your keepalive set to?  If you have no 'keepalive' set in your options, it will be disconnecting every 60 seconds or so, depending on what the broker is set to.

Comment: I use the default keepalive value which is 60. But those messages yield many times in 60 second.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64345725/edit) to show more of the code. Also which broker are you using, does it support MQTT v5?

Comment: I have wrote the whole code.
I use EMQ which support MQTT v5 as my broker.

Comment: "I have wrote the whole code" - so `topic` is undefined?

Comment: Topic is any string. Would Topic affect?

Comment: From [the spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800439) "A SUBSCRIBE packet with no payload is a protocol violation [MQTT-3.8.3-3]" and the broker must close the connection if there is a protocol violation. So yes a blank or non UTF-8 topic could cause this.

Comment: I mean the topic is like 'test' or anything else string.

Comment: As long as it's a valid topic it will not cause this issue (but as you indicated the code above was complete it was a possible cause; detail matters when diagnosing issues like this, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Also what is the time period between the `subscribed` and the `disconnect` and are you able to post the EMQ logs?